# Made a custom form module, form commits to database before entering values

Tags: php, database, phtml, form-validation

I have made a custom form module. However, the module already commits the "values" when I enter the page instead of after entering values and pressing on "submit". So every time I refresh the page my form submits a blank value towards my database.

[image]

The page also pushes the success value after refreshing the page:

> 'Succesfully asked a question!'

These are my files:
Block/List.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Class Topper_ProductQA_Block_List
 */
class Topper_ProductQA_Block_List extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

    /**
     * @return Topper_ProductQA_Model_Resource_Question_Collection
     */
    public function getQuestions()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('topperproductqa/question')->getCollection();

        return $collection;
    }

    /**
     * Class Topper_ProductQA_Block_List
     */
    public function getFormQuestions()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
        $form = Mage::getModel('topperproductqa/question');
        $form->setQuestion($data['question']);
        $form->setCustomerEmail($data['customer_email']);
        try {
            $form->save();
            $session->addSuccess('Succesfully asked a question!');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $session->addError('Error');
        }
    }
}
```

controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php

class Topper_ProductQA_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();

        return $this;

    }
}
```

Model/Question.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Class Topper_ProductQA_Model_Question
 *
 * @method string getQuestion()
 * @method setQuestion(string $question)
 *
 * @method string getAnswer()
 * @method setAnswer(string $answer)
 *
 * @method string getCreatedAt()
 * @method setCreatedAt(string $createdAt)
 *
 * @method string getUpdatedAt()
 * @method setUpdatedAt(string $updatedAt)
 *
 * @method string getCustomerEmail()
 * @method setCustomerEmail(string $customerEmail)
 */
class Topper_ProductQA_Model_Question extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Topper_ProductQA_Model_Question constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_init('topperproductqa/question');
    }

    public function _beforeSave()
    {
        if ($this->isObjectNew()) {
            $this->setCreatedAt(Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate());
        }

        $this->setUpdatedAt(Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate());
    }
}
```

template/list.phtml

```
<?php /** @var Topper_ProductQA_Block_List $this */ ?>

<!-- Tekst na submit -->
<span id="feedback-submit-button" style="display:none;">
Bedankt voor de vraag, wij koppelen zo snel mogelijk terug.
</span>

<!--Form-->
<form id="questionForm" method="post" action="<?php echo $this->getFormQuestions() ?>">
    <table>
        <col width="200">
        <col width="500">

        <!--Title-->
        <h2 class="legend">
            <?php echo $this->__('Ask a question!') ?>
        </h2>

        <!--Customer Email-->
        <div class="field">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="customer_email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('E-mail') ?></label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="customer_email" id="customer_email" title="<?php echo $this->__('E-mail') ?>"
                           class="input-text required-entry validate-email" maxlength="255" type="text"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </div>

        <!--Question-->
        <div class="field">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="question" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Question') ?></label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <textarea name="question" id="question" title="<?php echo $this->__('Question') ?>"
                              class="required-entry input-text" cols="5" rows="3"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </div>

        <!--Required Fields-->
        <p class="required">*
            <?php echo $this->__('Required Fields') ?>
        </p>

        <!--Submit button-->
        <button type="button" onclick="questionSubmit()" title="<?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?>" class="button">
            <span><span><?php echo('Submit') ?></span></span>
        </button>
    </table>
</form>

<!-- Validation -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var offerteForm = new VarienForm('questionForm', true);
    function questionSubmit() {
        if (offerteForm.validator.validate()) {
            new Ajax.Updater({success: 'questionForm1'}, '<?php echo $this->getUrl(); ?>productqa/index/index/',
                {
                    onComplete: function (request, json) {
                        Element.hide('questionForm');
                        Element.show('feedback-submit-button');
                    }
                });
            return false;
        }
    }
    //]]>
</script>


<br><br>




<!--Post Question & Answers-->
<ul>
    <?php /** @ var Topper_ProductQA_Model_Question $question */
    foreach ($this->getQuestions() as $questionanswer) : ?>

        <li><?php echo $questionanswer->getQuestion(); ?></li>
        <li><?php echo $questionanswer->getAnswer(); ?></li>
        <br>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your save code should be in controller. You have given form action as block code so every time when you refresh your page , your block will call and it will save value on refresh. Move your save code to controller

Answer (score 0):

you have this line in your template `<form id="questionForm" method="post" action="<?php echo $this->getFormQuestions() ?>">`.
So when the form is rendered, the method `getFormQuestions` is called. And this is the method that inserts data in your database.

Comment: I thought that if you submitted the form, THEN it would go to getFormQuestions and not when the page was rendered in the first place. My bad